# realm loop in one transaction VS one transaction for each stepin loop

Tags: java, android, transactions, realm

Which way is better?

1. One transaction with a loop inside

   ```
   public void saveProducts(List<Product> products) {

       Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
       realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {

           for (Product product : products) {
               Number currentIdNum = realm1.where(Product.class).max("id");
               long nextId;
               if (currentIdNum == null) {
                   nextId = 1;
               } else {
                   nextId = currentIdNum.longValue() + 1;
               }

               String code = product.getCategory().getCode();
               Category code1 = realm.where(Category.class).equalTo("code", code).findFirst();
               if (code1 == null) {
                   Category category = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(product.getCategory());
                   product.setCategory(category);
               } else {
                   product.setCategory(code1);
               }
               product.setId(nextId);
               realm1.insertOrUpdate(product); // using insert API
           }
       });
       realm.close();
   }
   ```
2. A loop with transactions for each element?

   ```
   public void saveProducts(List<Product> products) {

       Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
       for (Product product : products) {
           realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {
               Number currentIdNum = realm1.where(Product.class).max("id");
               long nextId;
               if (currentIdNum == null) {
                   nextId = 1;
               } else {
                   nextId = currentIdNum.longValue() + 1;
               }

               String code = product.getCategory().getCode();
               Category code1 = realm.where(Category.class).equalTo("code", code).findFirst();
               if (code1 == null) {
                   Category category = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(product.getCategory());
                   product.setCategory(category);
               } else {
                   product.setCategory(code1);
               }
               product.setId(nextId);
               realm1.insertOrUpdate(product); // using insert API

           });
       }
       realm.close();
   }
   ```

Or another way? If you know how to do it better please say.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for (Product product : products) {
>     realm.executeTransaction(realm1 ->
> ```

This one is much worse.

Prefer single transactions.

Comment: Thank you. and the approach in saving one to many is correct? I my code

Comment: It looks fine to me, although it depends on whether Category has a primary key; i'm guessing `code` is the PK which is good

Comment: public class Category extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String code;
    private String name;

    @LinkingObjects("category")
    private final RealmResults<Product> products = null;

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with Realm Proxy objects then you can follow this approach.

```
 public void saveProducts(List<Product> products) {

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();


    for (Product product : products) {


        Number currentIdNum = realm1.where(Product.class).max("id");
        long nextId;
        if (currentIdNum == null) {
            nextId = 1;
        } else {
            nextId = currentIdNum.longValue() + 1;
        }

        String code = product.getCategory().getCode();
        Category code1 = realm.where(Category.class).equalTo("code", code).findFirst();
        if (code1 == null) {
            Category category = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(product.getCategory());
            product.setCategory(category);
        } else {
            product.setCategory(code1);
        }
        product.setId(nextId);
        realm.insertOrUpdate(product); // using insert API



    }
    realm.commitTransaction();

    realm.close();
}
```

Comment: Why begin a new transaction per item?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i did that for scenario like suppose he need single object change listener. I have updated my answer for single time init and commit which can be considered as better approach.

Comment: It worked for me. Better then accepted answer. Thanks ;) +1